# Find what causes redirect with Google Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, debugging, console

A web site is loaded in Google Chrome. In several seconds redirect to another page happens. How to find what causes redirect to another page using Google Chrome Console?

Network tab in Google Console doesn't show what exactly causes this redirect.

Comment: I'm guessing you can't find the exact piece of code that redirected, so the first thing to do is look for a meta tag, then check the headers, then start reading all the javascript searching for `location` until you find it.

Comment: Yes as @adeneo said, try searching for `location` tags in the source code such as `window.location.replace`, `window.location.href`, etc. Hope this helps. Cheers!